# Get media file length in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to get any media file (.avi, .mp4, .mp3, etc.) length using Mac's Terminal?

I there is a need to install a package or a library can you please specify which, and how to install them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe` to get the duration. You can install `ffmpeg` easily using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

And then you can get the duration using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

See the answers here for more details: [How to get length of video file from console?](https://superuser.com/questions/361329/how-to-get-length-of-video-file-from-console)

Comment: Is it possible to sum up lengths of multiple files?

Comment: You can create a bash variable and increase it as you read the length of the files.

Answer (score 14):

Mac built in:

```
mdls *.mp4
```

Tested in MacOSX 10.6.8

Comment: This seems to be downvoted, and as-written it's not as helpful as it could be, but with some extra pipes it can be great, and doesn't require installing ffmpeg: `mdls *.mp4 | grep Duration | awk '{ print $3 }'`. To tally up the lengths of all files in a directory you can tack on `| paste -s -d+ - | bc`.

Comment: @DaveCeddia: There's never been any votes; see history. `mdls` & `mdfind` are built in Mac commands; they don't rely on (external) ffmpeg (installation). Your `grep`  relies on output of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Ah sorry, was thinking of a different voting system. My `grep` only relies on the output of `mdls` though... unless the output of `mdls` is different when ffmpeg is installed? I wouldn't think so? When I run `mdls` on a file it has a line that includes the string "Duration" (kMDItemDurationSeconds).

Comment: @DaveCeddia Or you can  `mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name Duration 1.mp4`

Comment: @est Fully agree, your solution is more explicit, and avoids a dependency on grep.  Using `mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds $file | awk '{ print $3 }'` solved this for me.

Comment: @est i get, Duration = (null). Do i have to update mdls because by the finder i can find the duration of that video. It seems the duration is only known by mdls when the video extension is mov.

Comment: @XamMlr - I have the same experience. Only MOV file shows Duration. MKV and MP4 does not.